# Load and show image in Xamarin with UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I am writing an Xamarin picture gallery app and my UWP app has broad file permissions and can load bytes from a random filepath, but I am not able to show these bytes with

```
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
```

This code is in the base project, where bytes are loaded via dependency service in UWP project from image file. The .xaml file contains following definition of the image:

```
<Image x:Name="image" Aspect="Fill"/>
```

After executing this code (imageBytes are not empty) the image is not shown on the interface.

But if I use

```
image.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("test.png");
```

the image from the resources is shown. So I assume the image should be visible if it is loaded correctly.
I have not tested the code with Android or iPhone because I mainly want to use it on Windows and maybe later on Android.
Can please anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or post a link to a working example code!

Kind regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am writing an Xamarin picture gallery app and my UWP app has broad file permissions and can load bytes from a random filepath, but I am not able to show these bytes with

There are many reasons cause this problem, if you load file from installedLocation folder like the following, you need make sure the file **Build Action** is `Content` type.

During the testing, it could load image bytes correctly and display image well. please try the following  DependencyService.

**Interface**

```
public interface IImageStream
{
    Task<byte[]> GetBytes();
}
```

**Implement**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyImageStream))]

public class MyImageStream :IImageStream
{

    public async Task<byte []> GetBytes()
    {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        StorageFile sampleFile = await installedLocation.GetFileAsync("test.png");

        byte[] result;
        using (Stream stream = await sampleFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                result = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
var imageBytes = await DependencyService.Get<IImageStream>().GetBytes();
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

With your code it works :)

I used another code for loading the bytes from the image, like in other pure UWP apps, where it works without any problem. But my method returns a different array of bytes. I dont know why it works in pure UWP apps. Maybe there the image view works different.

Kind regards,
Wolfgang